# Footer background-color disappears in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a really weird issue when I look at my website in a through a viewport of less than 768px. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6.

In a large browse it looks like this, the footer has a gray background:

[image]

But when I open it in mobile the `background-color: #eee;` disappears, along with

[image]

I want the footer to have a gray background in all viewports. I've been looking at this for hours and I can't figure it out what I've done wrong. I've tried in Chrome and Firefox and it looks the same. How do I fix this?

For some reason, I haven't been able to replicate the issue in a Fiddle, but I've [provided the code here](https://jsfiddle.net/hcgriggs/qv37h1v5/5/). I'm using jQuery Easing as well. Could this be interfering with the `divs`?

Comment: Your page URL? On jsfiddle everything looks fine

Comment: @DejanLacmanovic I'm hosting it locally on my computer. Could that be this issue? I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hcgriggs/qv37h1v5/5/